# Why is "0D0" considered numeric in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Any idea why `ISNUMERIC('0D0') = 1` is TRUE in SQL Server 2008?

I'm validating ID numbers from another system, which sometimes contain letters that we don't want to bring over, but this combination is tripping up the code (the specific ID that it thinks is numeric is "005406257D6"). Downstream we're doing `CONVERT(BIGINT, @val)`, which is obviously choking when it finds these "D" values.

What special case am I hitting, and how do I account for it?

Comment: +1 - Looks like it also works for 'E', but not for A-C (so it's not a HEX thing)...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358147/best-equivalent-for-isinteger-in-sql-server the Answer by gbn is interesting and worth a try IMO..

Comment: @JNK afaik "D" stands for Decimal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Basically, IsNumeric is useless - all it verifies is that the string can be converted to *any* of the numeric types. In this case, "0D0" can be converted to a float. (I can't remember the reason, but effectively "D" is a synonym for "E", and means it's scientific notation):

```
select CONVERT(float,'2D3')
```

> 2000

If you want to verify that it's just digits, then `not @val like '%[^0-9]%'` would be a better test. You can improve this further by adding a length check also.

Comment: Actually "0D0" LIKE '%[^0-9]%' is TRUE as well, but I see your point.

Comment: @gfrizzle - you missed the `not` at the start

Comment: @gfrizzle - you need to do a `NOT LIKE` on that expression since it has the `^` at the beginning indicating NOT.  I.e. you are asking "Is it NOT not all numbers?"

Comment: DOH! Thanks for setting me straight. :)

Answer (score 0):

An good explanation of why.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/IsNumeric/71512/

(below is @RedFilter's more exhaustive query/list)

```
SELECT  [Ascii Code] = STR(Number)
       ,[Ascii Character] = CHAR(Number)
       ,[ISNUMERIC Returns] = ISNUMERIC(CHAR(Number))
FROM    Master.dbo.spt_Values
WHERE   Type = 'P'
        AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 255
        AND ISNUMERIC(CHAR(Number)) = 1
UNION
SELECT  [Ascii Code] = STR(Number)
       ,[Ascii Character] = CHAR(Number)
       ,[ISNUMERIC Returns] = ISNUMERIC('0' + CHAR(Number) + '0')
FROM    Master.dbo.spt_Values
WHERE   Type = 'P'
        AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 255
        AND ISNUMERIC('0' + CHAR(Number) + '0') = 1
```

yeilds

```
Ascii Code Ascii Character
---------- ---------------
     0      
     9      
    10      
    11      
    12      
    13      
    36  $   
    43  +   
    44  ,   
    45  -   
    46  .   
    48  0   
    49  1   
    50  2   
    51  3   
    52  4   
    53  5   
    54  6   
    55  7   
    56  8   
    57  9   
    68  D   
    69  E   
    92  \   
   100  d   
   101  e   
   128  €   
   160      
   162  ¢   
   163  £   
   164  ¤   
   165  ¥
```

Comment: Actually, it should be `SELECT [Ascii Code] = STR(Number), 
[Ascii Character] = CHAR(Number), 
[ISNUMERIC Returns] = ISNUMERIC(CHAR(Number)) 
FROM Master.dbo.spt_Values 
WHERE Type = 'P' 
AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 255 
AND ISNUMERIC(CHAR(Number)) = 1 
union 
SELECT [Ascii Code] = STR(Number), 
[Ascii Character] = CHAR(Number), 
[ISNUMERIC Returns] = ISNUMERIC('0' + CHAR(Number) + '0') 
FROM Master.dbo.spt_Values 
WHERE Type = 'P' 
AND Number BETWEEN 0 AND 255 
AND ISNUMERIC('0' + CHAR(Number) + '0') = 1`

Comment: Thanks @RedFilter, I just copied/pasted from the article (since the site requires registration to view it). I incorporated your update.