# ISNumeric is buggy in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I do `ISNUMERIC('0E1') = 1`, it returns true. Can anyone explain how SQL server qualifies 'E' as numeric?

Is this the right way to check numbers in SQL? Sorry I am new to T-SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

0E1 is numeric. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_notation#E_notation

To allow only integers containing only numbers, see [Best equivalent for IsInteger in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358147/best-equivalent-for-isinteger-in-sql-server)

Comment: Ok but that ways, wrong data could go in the DB. How can I write this query so that sql server returns false