# Sql parse column as int and check if it is within range

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-attribute-value

I've used the top voted answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376695/sql-server-where-field-is-int) to check if a cell value is an integer. But I also need to do a range check on it.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE (dbo.IsInteger(FieldName) = 1) AND FieldName > 400 AND FieldName < 500
```

But this returns a conversion error, as some of the cells in the column contains text. So, is it possible to get a subset, that is only results from the `IsInteger` query, and then do a range check on the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap it in a `CASE` expression. I've altered the query slightly to use `BETWEEN` to avoid having to repeat the expression.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE CASE WHEN dbo.IsInteger(FieldName) = 1 
           THEN FieldName END BETWEEN 401 AND 499
```

The result of the expression will be `NULL` when `dbo.IsInteger(FieldName) <> 1` which will not match the `BETWEEN` predicate.

Of course this is completely unsargable but so is your original query.